# Constrained optimization with scipy: limiting value of a constraint coming from the objective function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to solve a constrained optimization problem of the form:

min_{x} f(x)

s.t.

x >= x_min

with f(x) a non-linear function of x.

The issue is that x_min comes from evaluating f(x), i.e.:

```
def f(x):
    ...
    return cost_value, x_min
```

To solve the problem, I want to use the `SLSQP` algorithm in `scipy.optimize.minimize`, so I can create a constraint function such as:

```
def constraint(x):
    _, x_limit = f(x)
    value = x - x_limit
    return value
```

and then pass it to the call to the optimizer:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint})
solution = minimize(fun=f,
                    x0=x_seed,
                    constraints=constraints)
```

In my real problem, evaluating `f(x)` is fairly expensive (it is a chemical process simulation that takes about 20-30 seconds per run), thus, caling `f(x)` inside `constraint` to get `x_lim` is not desirable.

I was wondering if there is a recursive way to avoid calling the objective function inside `constraint` function, and still having the value of `x_lim` available to compute the inequality.

Comment: I would not recommend SLSQP at all for this. Ignoring your problem here, everything using gradients or hessians will use numerical-diff if you don't give these a-priori and this will be incredibly slow (high number of function-evaluations). Furthermore these optimizers post some assumptions about your function/constraints (e.g. smoothness) which might not be the case. Anf if your evaluation is somewhat noisy, you got another problem (especially in combination with numerical-gradients). Look for global-optimization / black-box optimization.

Comment: Thanks sascha for your input. I agree with you when you point out that in this particular case, using a gradient-based optimization algorithm would lead to slow executions. However, I think that if there is a nice way to avoid several objective function evaluations for constraints, it would be useful in other scenarios where gradients are available. I know that a possible way to skip this problem is to penalize the objective function, but I wanted a more direct way using the capabilities of the constrained optimizer.

Comment: If you are just asking about how not to recompute f(x), then just build a memoization-wrapper, which holds the last evaluation or multiple ones in a dictionary. Something [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418312/can-i-pass-the-objective-and-derivative-functions-to-scipy-optimize-minimize-as). There was some other answer here doing the same (without lru_cache) where one comment mentions that there is something like that built-in for at least tnc i think. But i don't have a link.